# Create command line tool for Aptana Studio 3 like in Sublime Text 4 Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, aptana3, command-line-tool

I am trying the Ruby On Rails Tutorial (railstutorial.org) and want to use Aptana Studio 3, however, the author gives a few abbreviations for gvim, subl or mate, not Aptana.  How can I do this http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html to work with aptana instead of sublime ???  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't currently have Aptana Studio 3 installed in this computer but I found this answer by a quick Google lookup of `aptana command line`

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/getting_started

It basically says aptana provides a command line tool called `studio3`

Here's what it says

> If getting your login PATH set up in this way isn't practical for you, you can work around the problem by launching Aptana Studio 3 from the command line, using the studio3 command line utility. This utility can be found at the top level of the Aptana Studio 3 installation folder, so you can put that folder in your PATH for convenience. (The command line utility can also be called after Aptana Studio 3 is running, to get it to open source code files for editing.)